# Using javascript promises to return array upon a certain criterion

Tags: javascript, arrays, callback, promise

I am querying an API to get a list of songs. I then use each song to again, query the API to get its lyrics. The problem is that since the API calls are asynchronous the array of lyrics returns without getting a chance to be filled. I only want to return the array once all the lyrics have been inserted.

```
const request = require('request')

function getTracks(num_artists, country) { 
    return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
        request('http://api.musixmatch.com/ws/1.1/chart.tracks.get?page=1&page_size='+num_artists+'&country='+country+'&f_has_lyrics=1&apikey=myKey', { json: true }, (err, res, body) => {
          resolve(res.body.message.body.track_list);
          reject(err);      
        });     
    });
}

function getLyrics(track_id){ 
    return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
        request('http://api.musixmatch.com/ws/1.1/track.lyrics.get?track_id='+track_id+'&apikey=myKey', { json: true }, (err, res, body) => {
            resolve(res.body.message.body.lyrics.lyrics_body);
            reject(err);
        });
    });
}

let lyrics_arr = getTracks(2, 'ca').then((tracks)=>{
    var arr = [] //I realise I can clean up the code by using the map 
    // function on the tracks array but I want to see exactly whats happening
    for (var i = tracks.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        getLyrics(tracks[i].track.track_id).then((lyrics)=>{
            arr.push(lyrics);
        });
    } //edit I have added the closing brace for the for loop
    return arr;
});
```

Ideally I would like to eventually have a function that returns the array so that I can include this script in another file and use the functions to query the API from there. 
Any suggestions?
Thank you

Comment: use Promise.all

Comment: you didn't close the `for()` loop `{}`

Comment: Thanks I've closed the for loop.When I console.log the arr at the end of the for loop i get an empty array. I'm guessing it's because the line runs before the array is filled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: OK, isolated all the potentials errors, now with the solution. Capture your promises inside the loop into an array and then wait for them all to resolve thus:

```
    getTracks(2, 'ca').then((tracks)=>{
       var promises = [];
       for(...) {
          var promise = getLyrics(...);
          promises.push(promise);
       }
       return Promise.all(promises);
    }
```

And that should do it!

**Then from another file:**

```
getTracks2(...).then(/* deal with data here */);
```

=====

Looks good if you add the closing the `}` needed by the `for` loop. Assumes variable names are all pointing at the correct things, and that no rejects for the promises.

Your code is a bit abstract, but it is likely the `request()` function already returns a promise. I can't tell based upon your code (the Fetch API?). If it does, there is no reason to create a wrapper promise.

Comment: Thanks for the response. However, I can't seem to console.log anything other than an empty array which is my original problem. If my promise is redundant shouldn't I at least get an array containing the lyrics? I don't see how that could cause an issue.

Comment: Right - where is the `request()` function coming from?

Comment: Request is a node module that I include at the start of the script using const request = require('request'). I should probably include that in the question.

Comment: @user3117051- need to see the tracks data. console.log(tracks) pls and place it here.

Comment: `[ { track: 
     { track_id: 146161699,
       track_mbid: '',
       ... } },
  { track: 
     { track_id: 144542550,
       track_mbid: '',
       ... } } ]
`I have left out the other fields in the objects as the output was too long. However I only need the track_id to query the API for lyrics.

Comment: OK..must be a tiny dataset. It is definitely racing. I'll amend my answer in a minute. Essentially, you'll have to capture all the promises and then deal with them once they all resolve. Probably using Promise.all()

Comment: @user3117051 -all set, please see amended answer

Comment: @user3117051 - Did that work for you? If so, and my answer was acceptable, please accept my answer. thanks!

Comment: This works for printing out the data but my goal is to be able to return this data so that I can use it elsewhere. Is that possible? I plan to import this script into another file and use the function `getTracks` to obtain this data.

Comment: Hi sure, I think the easiest way then would be to return the `Promise.all()` statement. Please the edited answer

Comment: @user3117051 - I just realized I made a mistake in my example above. I forgot to remove the `.then(..)` bit. Fixed now.

Comment: is `getTracks2` in the other file going to be an object with the return value of getTracks?

Comment: No, it will be a promise that will `resolve` with the data that you printed out earlier, or it will `reject` if something goes wrong. Please read up on the Promise API here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Comment: Because after your last edit I had a follow on question which you've now answered so I've accepted it again. Thanks for your help

Comment: Awesome - glad to help!